# Need to get only Unit Test Coverage results using SONAR

Tags: code-coverage, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

Is there any way I could JUST get the unit test code coverage results on SONAR. My project is to just focus on the code coverage and not on code issues/violations/rules etc.

It would be a big time saver for me. As the project that I am dealing with has million lines of code. I have all my jacoco.exec files generated and appended. Sonar analyses in and out of our code and which takes hours. code standards,rules,violations,issues for which my project is not concerned off.

Any help on this would be highly appreciative.

Regards
Eajaz

Answer (score 2):

This is really an edge case for the use of SonarQube.

If you use an empty quality profile for analysis, you should not get any issue on your code, only metrics - including coverage, which seems your main concern.